# Weil(,) als er ankam

Tags: comma

Könnten Sie mir sagen, welche der Sätze das Komma brauchen?

1. Er sagte das, weil(,) als er zu Hause ankam, er Ärger hatte.
2. Tom behauptete, dass(,) weil sein Vater hartnäckig sei, er von zu Hause weggehe.
3. Ich wurde müde und(,) als sie zu mir kam, konnte ich ihr nicht helfen.
4. Aber(,) wenn du erwachsen wirst, mein Kind, wirst du ein verantwortlicher Wächter.

Comment: Eine Frage sollte ein Problem formulieren und nicht nur nach der Korrektheit fragen. Warum ist die Kommasetzung hier unklar? Was sagen die amtlichen Regeln oder andere Quellen? Was ist deiner Meinung nach korrekt und warum?

Comment: Das erledigen wir halt in der Antwort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 The word order is stylistically odd, better: "Er sagte das, weil er, als er zu Hause ankam, Ärger hatte" ("weil + Pronoun" should not be separated. With comma, the subordinate clause is inserted into the main clause and marked with commas as a whole)

2 With comma, but the ordering is odd here, too.

3 "Ich wurde müde, und als sie zu mir kam, konnte ich ihr nicht helfen." (comma before "und" when there is a new main clause and the subject changes, this also corresponds to an intonational break. When you start another main clause with "als...", the comma only marks the boundary where the subordinate clause ends. This "als"-clause is in the Vorfeld / 1st position of a verb-second clause.)

4 No comma after "aber": "aber wenn" can be treated as a unit (like "auch wenn" etc.)

A comma between pre-Vorfeld material and main clause (verb-2nd clause) only appears if it is an item that is clearly independent, like "*Ehrlich gesagt,* wenn ..., dann..."